# Python splitting a string with accented letters

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, diacritics, non-ascii-characters, python-unicode

I would like to split a string which contains accented characters into characters without breaking the accent and the letter apart.

A simple example is

```
>>> o = u"šnjiwgetit"
>>> print u" ".join(o)
s ̌ n j i w g e t i t
```

or

```
>>> print list(o)
[u's', u'\u030c', u'n', u'j', u'i', u'w', u'g', u'e', u't', u'i', u't']
```

Whereas I would like the result to be `š n j i w g e t i t` so that the accent stays on top of the consonant.

The solution should work even with more difficult characters such as `h̭ɛ̮ŋkkɐᴅ`

Comment: Does `' '.join(unicodedata.normalize('NKFC', o))` do what you want? Think that's the right mode to use as that `s` thing is probably something that needs combining to make it a single character.

Comment: ' '.join(unicodedata.normalize('NKFC', o)) gives ValueError: invalid normalization form

Comment: Oops... NFKC...

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work for most of the cases. Although, I would really appreciate a solution that works even with more difficult cases such as h̭ɛ̮ŋkkɐᴅ. With unicodedata.normalize it still outputs as  h ̭ ɛ ̮ ŋ k k ɐ ᴅ

Comment: Until someone comes along that is very well versed in the nuances of Unicode - I'd probably read up a bit on the Python Unicode HOWTO and what all those modes for `unicodedata.normalize` do...

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the other example you've cited please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to group the characters. Here is a sample code for doing so:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'(\w[\u02F3\u1D53\u0300\u2013\u032E\u208D\u203F\u0311\u0323\u035E\u031C\u02FC\u030C\u02F9\u0328\u032D:\u02F4\u032F\u0330\u035C\u0302\u0327\u03572\u0308\u0351\u0304\u02F2\u0352\u0355\u00B7\u032C\u030B\u2019\u0339\u00B4\u0301\u02F1\u0303\u0306\u030A7\u0325\u0307\u0354`\u02F0]+|\w|\W)', re.UNICODE | re.IGNORECASE)
```

In case you had some accents missing, add them the pattern.

Then, you can split words into characters as follows.

```
print(list(pattern.findall('šnjiwgetit')))
['š', 'n', 'j', 'i', 'w', 'g', 'e', 't', 'i', 't'
print(list(pattern.findall('h̭ɛ̮ŋkkɐᴅ')))
['h̭', 'ɛ̮', 'ŋ', 'k', 'k', 'ɐ', 'ᴅ']
```

If you are using Python2, add `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the beginning of the file.